# Is it possible to test ready ipa file by instruments

Tags: ios, deployment, air, adobe, instruments

I have an application built in IPA file by Adobe Flashbuilder (with AIR) the app works smoothly on iPad. Well.. worked smoothly until I had encountered some memory leaks. Is it possible to monitor this application's memory usage with Apple's Instruments?

For now I am deploying this app by dragging IPA file into iTunes and synchronize then.

I need to monitor this app. Is it possible? What should be eventually done to make it working?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. you can analyse using instruments.

1. Install your app in your device.
2. Connect your device to your Mac.
3. Open Instruments and select Leaks (you can select any option infact, like Allocations etc.,) in the dialog that appears.
4. In the Top Left corner, you will see "Choose Target". the first two options are your device and your Mac. Select your device.
5. In the same menu, the 5th option is again "Choose Target". There you will see all the installed applications in your device. Select the app you want to analyse.
6. Finally, Press Record, and you will see your app running in the device and Leaks/Allocations (whatever you have selected) being shown in the instruments.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Try running Instruments and select an installed app on your device, if you get this message, you know what's happening

> Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.fantageek.MyApp was
>   denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS
>   Developer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible through the Xcode organiser. It outputs events happening on the device to a log. Don't quote me on that though